# How to convert an Enhanced Windows Metafile (emf) to a JPG or PNG without loosing quality?

Tags: graphics, tableau-api

I am using Tableau to do some data representations and the only good quality image export Tableau allows is *.emf

Unfortunately, the online tool I use to put the report together(Canva) does not support emf format.

When I convert the file to jpg or png, the quality is drastically reduced :(

How can I overcome this matter? I tried many things such as opening emf in Illustrator and saving back with CMYK colors and 300dpi and such. But nothing seems to keep the crisp quality of the original emf file.

Comment: EMF is vector graphics so converting to lossy raster JPG will always be a bad choice. PNG is OK but you need to use target image resolution the same as the presenting one otherwise scalling artifacts will occur. The only true lossless conversion is doable only to a vector format like SVG,DWG,DXF,... As the EMF file format is not that complex writing a decoder is a possibility too (enabling EMF files in your app) IIRC EMF was supported in Windows natively (like their 16 bit counterpart WMF) but MS disable it after founding out they are used to breach security (instead of patching the hole)

Answer (score 1):

User Friendly solution:
InkScape opens enhanced windows metafiles, and many other vector-graphical file formats.
It exports to png with choice for output's resolution 
It is opensource and available for Linux, windows and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fact that Tableau's image export feature does not provide many options. In general when I need high quality images, I use one of the below methods depending on the quality I need and the tools available to me at that time:

- Screenshot method: If you have a large screen, taking a screenshot directly from Tableau yields better images than the exported ones. If my viz is exported to web, I sometimes enlarge the graphic from my web browser and then take the screenshot.
- Converting from PDF: Since PDF can contain vector objects, Tableau's PDF files are in high quality most of the times. If you cannot use these PDF files, you may try converting these files to PNG or JPG files using online or desktop tools. [Here](http://pdf2png.com/) is an online tool you may use for this purpose, but be careful about your confidential files when using such online services :)
- And there are more ways to convert from PDF but are usually more complicated since they contain some Photoshop steps. I am not sure whether these are easy to apply methods for a lot of files but still you may want to check one of them: https://community.tableau.com/thread/120134